# To generate a run ID during each run and reflect it in Maven Reports

Tags: maven, junit, report, buildnumber-maven-plugin

I want to generate a run ID for each run in maven. For example if i run a test cases; a run id should be included in the report that can be used for identifying that test case run. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Build Number Maven Plugin to create the number and then load it whereever you need it.

http://mojo.codehaus.org/buildnumber-maven-plugin/